# How can we discover the cost of maintaining materialized views?

Tags: google-bigquery

Materialized views are great however there is a cost associated with the jobs that maintain them. We want to create a materialized view over the top of a table into which we're streaming about 50million events per day and are worried about the cost implication of that materialized view.

How can we track the cost of maintaining those materialized views?

Comment: Have you looked at this view -- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-jobs#schema. 

Also, there are a set of best practices mentioned for materialized view maintenance-- doc --> https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views-best-practices#when-maintain. I believe these links should help.

Comment: I have not, but they look useful. Do you know how I could isolate jobs that are specific to materialized table rebuilds/maintenance?

Comment: Try this 
````select  ref_tabls.table_id,jobs.*
    from    `planar-effect-325211`.`region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT jobs, 
    unnest(referenced_tables) as ref_tabls
    left join `planar-effect-325211`.`region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES tb
    on ref_tabls.table_id = tb.table_name
    where   tb.table_type = 'MATERIALIZED VIEW'
````

Note - I have not tried this as I am not having upgraded instance of BQ. Replace region-us with your region.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
select  ref_tabls.table_id,jobs.*     
from    `project-id`.`region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT jobs,
unnest(referenced_tables) as ref_tabls     
left join `project-id`.`region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES tb     
on ref_tabls.table_id = tb.table_name     
where   tb.table_type = 'MATERIALIZED VIEW'
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this for past 7 days queries, but it seems it cost half of that

```sql
SELECT
  query
  , SUM(total_slot_ms) / (1000 * 60 * 60) AS slot_hours
  , SUM(total_bytes_processed) / 1000 / 1000 / 1000 AS gb_processed
  , (SUM(total_slot_ms) / (1000 * 60 * 60)) * 0.04 AS slot_hours_usd
  , (SUM(total_bytes_processed) / 1000 / 1000 / 1000 / 1000) * 6.25 AS tb_processed_usd
  , (SUM(total_slot_ms) / (1000 * 60 * 60)) * 0.04 + (SUM(total_bytes_processed) / 1000 / 1000 / 1000 / 1000) * 6.25 AS cost_usd 
  , ((SUM(total_slot_ms) / (1000 * 60 * 60)) * 0.04 + (SUM(total_bytes_processed) / 1000 / 1000 / 1000 / 1000) * 6.25) / COUNT(1) AS usd_per_query 
  , COUNT(1) AS query_count
FROM
  `region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS
WHERE
  creation_time BETWEEN TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 8 DAY) AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
  AND end_time BETWEEN TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
  AND (total_slot_ms > 0 OR total_bytes_processed > 0)
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 6 DESC;
```